# Excel: creating a number coloumn based on ID

Tags: excel, equation

I am trying to achieve this on excel but I don't know how I can do this.  Can someone help?

```
ID        Number
123001      1
123001      2      
155001      1
155001      2
155001      3
156003      1
147009      1
147009      2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `ID` occupies cell A1, you can use this formula

`=IF(A2=A1,B1+1,1)`

in cell B2 and copy this formula downwards. I'm assuming that the repeated `ID`s are grouped in the same block.